# Detecting Modal Sheet On Drag Down Event

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

Is it possible to intercept the event when the bottom sheet is being drag down, and show a message when it is about to close?

Comment: If you simply want to get notified when the bottom sheet closes, you can rely on the controller returned by showBottomSheet() which exposes [closed().](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/PersistentBottomSheetController-class.html#closed)

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

i added bool variable that check bottomSheet is open or closed,
(also this action i printout in appBar).

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}
class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  bool isOpen = false;

  var bottomSheetController;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: isOpen?Text("Open Bottom Sheet"):Text("Closed Bottom Sheet"),
      ),
        body:
        FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              isOpen = !isOpen;
            });
            print('clicked on the bottom sheet');
            if(isOpen) {
              bottomSheetController = showBottomSheet(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                  context: context,
                  builder: (ctx) {
                    return ClipRRect(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                        topRight: Radius.circular(20),
                        topLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                      ),
                      child: Container(
                          height: 150,
                          color: Colors.black,
                          child: TextField()
                      ),
                    );
                  });
              bottomSheetController.closed.then((value) {
                setState(() {
                  isOpen = !isOpen;
                });
              });
            } else {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
              setState(() {
                isOpen = !isOpen;
              });
            }
          },
          child: isOpen?Icon(Icons.arrow_downward):Icon(Icons.arrow_upward),
        ),
      );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a definitive answer, but I'm posting here because it provides a direction and is too long for a comment (because of links).

BottomSheet class defines [BottomSheetDragStartHandler](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/bf2c9dfc05a6d281e7d303689f1af9add4030230/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/bottom_sheet.dart#L29) which is a callback for when the user begins dragging the bottom sheet.

_ModalBottomSheet passes [this](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/bf2c9dfc05a6d281e7d303689f1af9add4030230/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/bottom_sheet.dart#L355) as onDragStart and [this](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/bf2c9dfc05a6d281e7d303689f1af9add4030230/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/bottom_sheet.dart#L360) as onDragEnd argument to it's BottomSheet child.

So in theory, if you really want to, you can implement custom bottom sheet following the example of _ModalBottomSheet and tailoring the stuff according to need.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this Widget: [BottomSheet](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomSheet-class.html).
It offers methods: `onDragStart()`, `onDragEnd()` and a more useful method:`onClosing` which exactly does what you're looking for.

```dart
    BottomSheet(
      enableDrag: true  // required
      onClosing: () {
        /* intercept close event */
        showDialog();
      }
    )
```

However, the only caveat here is, we can only use this `BottomSheet` in a `Scaffold`.

```dart
  Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(...),
    body: Container(...),
    bottomSheet: BottomSheet(
      onClosing: () {},
      builder: () => Container(...),
    )   
  )
```

This results in a persistent bottom sheet. To control its visibility, you will have to use a Stateful widget and have a boolean flag for the purpose.

**[See here](https://codesinsider.com/flutter-bottom-sheet-example-tutorial/) for a complete example.**